# Пунктуация. Запятая между ОЧП

Tags: пунктуация

Вы, владея участком земли, можете сдать его во временное пользование другим лицам на договоренных условия, (эта запятая носит уточнительный характер или она разделяет однородные члены предложения?) за плату.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая смысловая, стало быть, всё зависит от автора.

Если её не ставить, то будут неизвестные нам "договоренные условия" и условие известное - "за плату".

Если поставить, то "плата" становится ОЧП: она и есть эти "договоренные условия".

Comment: В итоге эта запятая соединяет ОЧП?

Comment: § 143. Запятая ставится между однородными членами предложения, не соединёнными посредством союзов. Примечание 1. Два или несколько прилагательных, согласованных с одним и тем же существительным и не соединённых между собой посредством союзов, **являются однородными только в том случае, пока каждое из них непосредственно относится к этому существительному**: http://n-t.ru/ac/56/pz03.htm - то есть всё сводится к вкладываемому автором смыслу.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, нужно говорить, в зависимости от смысла, о пояснительных членах предложения (на договоренных условиях, (то есть) за плату) или уточняющих членах предложения (на договоренных условиях, (как именно?) за плату).

См. [Уточняющие, пояснительные и присоединительные члены предложения](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html)